# Event listener function executing on assignment?

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I must be missing something incredibly simple here, but I cannot for the life of me figure it out.  Why does the page below execute the `alert` on page load, and not on button click as intended?  I am attempting to assign the `clicky()` function to the event listener (this assignment happens at page load), but instead the actual alert happens at page load (i.e. the clicky function gets called), and the button never gets its listener.  What am I missing?

```
<html>
<head>
<script>

function clicky() {
    alert("clicky");
}

function start() {
    var myButton = document.getElementById("theButton");
    myButton.addEventListener("onclick", clicky(), false);
}

window.onload = start;

</script>
</head>

<body>
<input type="button" id="theButton" value="I'm a button!">
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: When you add parenthesis to the function, it executes right away, drop the parenthesis -> `myButton.addEventListener("onclick", clicky, false);`

Comment: @adeneo You are correct, that prevents it from executing at page load.  But it still does not get attached properly as an event listener, so there must be a further problem.

Comment: I figured it out.  The correct event was `click`, not `onclick`.

Comment: Yepp, in an event listener the "on" prefix is not used, it's well documented on the [MDN pages](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.addEventListener)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try 'click' instead of 'onclick' in your call to addEventListener.

Answer (score 1):

You're adding what clicky() returns as the listener, not clicky itself. clicky() returns nothing (undefined) and that's why no handler is being attached. Just get rid of the parenthesis.

// Edit: Oh, I can see that was only half of the problem.